# Can't connect to SQL Server database inside %appdata% folder

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string, appdata

I use :

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/DomainModel.csdl|res://*/DomainModel.ssdl|res://*/DomainModel.msl;
                  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                  provider connection string=&quot;
                  data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                  AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.mdf;
              Database=MyDatabase;
              Trusted_Connection=True;
                  Integrated Security=SSPI;
              User Instance=True;
                  multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                  App=EntityFramework&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

The database `.mdf` is in the same folder with the app .EXE and the application works fine.

But when I change the connection string to:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/DomainModel.csdl|res://*/DomainModel.ssdl|res://*/DomainModel.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                       provider connection string=&quot;
                       data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                       AttachDBFileName=|%appdata%|MyDatabase.mdf;
               Database=MyDatabase;
               Trusted_Connection=True;
                       Integrated Security=SSPI;
               User Instance=True;
                       multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                       App=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

and pasted the `.mdf` to `%appdata%` folder, my app can't connect to the database.

Is there anything wrong with the connection string?

Comment: This post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037937/appdata-in-connection-string-is-not-substituted-for-the-actual-folder