# .NET embedded SQLite database file on deployment

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, deployment

I am deploying the .NET/WPF application that uses SQLite database as back-end and Entity Framework for CRUD operations with that file.

I want that the end users after installing the application will have that SQLite file on they local computer (is it /Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming/MyApp or something else ?).

During the development I have had the SQLite file located on my local folder and everything has worked fine. **How do I configure the application before deploying it** to get that result?

Comment: Just change the file path. What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: Change the file path is pretty vague -> Currently, in the project I can find my local folder path defined in several places across the application. I app.config file under <MySettings> and <connectionStrings> as well as in Settings.settings file and Settings.Designer.vb file. Is it ok I just manually overwrite all those paths before deploying? And what folder should I refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great answer from another question: [%APPDATA% in connection string is not substituted for the actual folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037937/appdata-in-connection-string-is-not-substituted-for-the-actual-folder)

What was needed was:

1. Changing connection string to include |DataDirectory| in the path to
   the database file and;
2. Providing the value for |DataDirectory| in the application Main method

   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))