# DataDirectory is not getting replaced in my code WPF - app.config

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, connection-string, app-config

I've been trying to set a connectionstring to the users programdata folder and followed the first step in the answer of this post:

[%APPDATA% in connection string is not substituted for the actual folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037937/appdata-in-connection-string-is-not-substituted-for-the-actual-folder)

Unfortunately I can't get it to work:

In the onstartup method of my WPF application I run the following:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData));

var test = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");

var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
```

Value in App.config

```
<add name="Conn" connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\mydb" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
```

result of test = "c:\programdata" => this is good

result of connectionstring ="|DataDirectory|\mydb"  => this is not good

I'm expecting:  "c:\programdata\mydb"

I've been looking all around... what am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how it works.
Setting the DataDirectory is correct, but the actual connectionstring is not changed on file.
When you open the connection the `|DataDirectory|` part of the string will be replaced with your path

You just need to try and see by yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the answer you linked to, you seem to be missing the following from Step 2. in the link:

```
 return connection.Replace("%APPDATA%",
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```