# creating a CompactSql database and adding its connection string to entity Framework dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

I'm working in c# WinForms, 4.8 .NET Framework, with Entity 6.

After more research, I found something that helped me:

1 - added this to app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="DatabaseEntities"
     connectionString="data source=%APPDATA%\writerapp.sdf, Password = 'writerapp'"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

2 - changed my main form, in the constructor, to call this method:

```
    private void InitializeApp()
    {
        var strCount = ("; Password = 'writerapp'").Length;
        var _conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString;
        var _conString = _conStr.Replace("%APPDATA%", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
        var _trimToFile = _conString.Remove(_conString.Length - strCount, strCount);

        if (File.Exists(_trimToFile))
        {
            Settings.Default.LocalConString = _conStr;
            Settings.Default.LocalDbPath = _trimToFile;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(_conString);
            en.CreateDatabase();

            if (File.Exists(_trimToFile))
            {
                Settings.Default.LocalConString = _conStr;
                Settings.Default.LocalDbPath = _trimToFile;
            }

            else throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

3 - Changed my DbContext to this:

```
 public class WriterAppContext : DbContext
{
    public WriterAppContext() : base(GetConnectionString()) { }

    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.LocalConString) 
          && File.Exists(Settings.Default.LocalDbPath)) 
          return Settings.Default.LocalConString;
        else throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DbSet<NotificationHandler> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks to: [%APPDATA% in connection string is not substituted for the actual folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037937/appdata-in-connection-string-is-not-substituted-for-the-actual-folder)

But I get an error :

> System.ArgumentException: 'Le format de la chaîne d'initialisation n'est pas conforme à la spécification qui débute à l'index 0.'

Means: The format of the initialization chain is not conform to the specification that starts at Index 0.

So I'm in the dark as to where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out my problem:

The password doesn't ask for the <**'**> contrary to what the answer to the thread I was following is saying. Plus I separated them with <**,**> instead of <**;**>

Two changes were to be made:

`connectionString="data source=%APPDATA%\writerapp.sdf; Password = writerapp"`

```
   var strCount = ("; Password = writerapp").Length;
   var strCount2 = ("data source=").Length;
   var _conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString;
            var _conString = _conStr.Replace("%APPDATA%", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
            var _cleanPath = _conString.Remove(0, strCount2);
            var _trimToFile = _cleanPath.Remove(_cleanPath.Length - strCount, strCount);
```

An with that, the problem was finally solved for good. This solution also work if I pick any location I want since I replace the connection string by what I want.

Hope this help anybody else to!